# Notepad++ : Set specific encoding for openging file

Tags: notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ on windows 10.

My question is how I can enforce notepad++ to use "OEM-US" as default encoding when I'm opening a file ?

For creating a file, you can do that by going to "Parameter > Settings > New Document".
But for opening a file, I'm at loss.

Worse, I can create a new file (which have "OEM-US", as expected), write something like "éèê", save it, close it, and when I'm reopening it, it's encodging change for "ANSI", messing the text previously wrote (now "‚Šˆ") !

I know that in many case, you simply can't know the file's encoding, but I would have tougth that there would be a setting for when I'm opening a file !

So long question short : How can I say to notepad++ "all file should be opened with this encoding" ?

In case this is important, windows default text encoding seem to be "iso-8859-1" (obtained with PowerShell [System.Text.Encoding]::Default command)

```
IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : iso-8859-1
EncodingName      : Europe de l'Ouest (Windows)
HeaderName        : Windows-1252
WebName           : Windows-1252
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 1252
```

Comment: You might ask on the Notepad++ forum at https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/ .